# what should be my initial address for sitemap and robots.txt if I'm using redirection

Tags: redirects, sitemap, robots.txt, webserver

What should be my initial adress when using this site: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com?

I have a folder inside my root where I have all my files.

For example I have `example.com` and my start directory is `example.com/en` so I have made a redirection to `example.com/e`n but the main question is what should be the starting point for sitemap: `example.com` or `example.com/en`?
Same thing is with `robots.txt`, should I put it in the root or in the en folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want both in the root of the site, especially robots.txt because that's where Bot's will be looking for it. The Sitemap could go anywhere, but it would make the most sense in your case to put it in the root, rather than having several sitemaps for each additional language you add in the future.